# How to improve the final image quality and clarity in Python PIL?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have been working on a POC which required Image Processing using PIL to extract the reading from the dials. The image processing steps are 1.

1. Cropping
2. Equalizing
3. Thresholding
4. Filtering
5. Inverting.

This process worked quite well for some images. For example:

Higher Resolution:
 [image: Working: Higher Resolution]

Same image of lower resolution when processed:

[image: Working: Lower Resolution]

Now I have a different sets of image which is spoiled due to a bit of shadowing and the images after image processing comes out like this:

Higher Resolution:

[image: Not Working:Higher Resolution]

Same image of lower resolution when processed:

[image: Not Working:Lower Resolution]

The lower portion is whitened a bit due to the shadowing and there is no reliable result which follows.

Can anyone suggest any solution for this problem??

Comment: You need some noise reduction technique at the start. Median filtering might help.

Comment: Mind that that `2. Equalization` step is further deteriorating the images, I would suggest you to go with `Blur` of some kind, and then perform the thresholding, the `Equalization` is dispersing the color spectrum which later causes problem in thresholding, Also You must see the method of resizing the images, There other methods like `Bilateral filtering`, `INTER_CUBIC`, etc. which create a sharp image while resizing the given image to lower resolution.

Comment: i have tried median filtering and bilateral as well as any other filter i got in the opencv doc. Thats not helping in any way.

Comment: Intercubic is for sharpening the image. though i have tried and didn't achieve much results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit late but answering the question as i have solved it. 
I have used the following steps.

1. contrast improvement
2. Threshold
3. inverted the logic for finding out the needle positions of finding out the angle where there are more number of black pixel. (earlier i used to count the angle where there are more number of white pixel)
   ignored steps from before are equalizing and inverting. 
   Results as below

   [image: inversion][image: calculation of angle]

Comment: yup it worked..but depends on the image intensity and resolution